# How to create directory from magento in the root of cpanel?

Tags: magento, mkdir

I am working in magento. I want to create a directory in the root of cpanel. But it gives me a error like this:

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied  in /home/testing/public_html/indies_installer/app/code/local/Indies/Installer/controllers/Adminhtml/InstallerController.php on line 53
#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'mkdir() [saveAction()
#3 /home/testing/public_html/indies_installer/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#4 /home/testing/public_html/indies_installer/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /home/testing/public_html/indies_installer/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /home/testing/public_html/indies_installer/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/testing/public_html/indies_installer/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

I am using

```
mkdir("/home/testing/public_html/test/",0777);
```

to create a directory from magento module. So, please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: does your user have mkdir persmission at all? Moreover are you sure that this path is correct? Also check test directory permissions.

Comment: @JevgeniSmirnov I have set the permission to 777. It does not work.

Comment: try to remove last '/' from path specified

Answer (score 1):

The hosting not allowed to create a folder under that folder. If you need you can create a folder inside Magento root directory.

Comment: Hosting allowed me to create a folder in the root. But from magento it does not allowed me to create a folder in the root of cpanel.

Comment: mkdir("/home/testing/public_html/test/",0777);  i am using this code to create a directory from magento in cpanel.